# Sorting an array of objects but prioritising certain items

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

Here's a sample data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "test",
    "is_folder": "Y",
    "is_file": "N",
    "sort": 0,
    "sort_reverse": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "1.jpg",
    "is_folder": "N",
    "is_file": "Y",
    "sort": 1,
    "sort_reverse": 0
  }
]
```

The idea is that the folders will always be at the top of the list followed by the files but I also want the folders and files to be sorted.

Example result:

Ascending (Default):

- Folder 1
- Folder 2
- Folder 3
- 1.jpg
- 2.jpg
- 3.jpg

Descending (Reverse):

- Folder 3
- Folder 2
- Folder 1
- 3.jpg
- 2.jpg
- 1.jpg

How can I achieve this with my sample data?

Here is what I've got so far to sort the names but no taking into account the folder/file order:

```
items.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    if (a.name > b.name) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a.name < b.name) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to consider: *if both items are folders or both items are not folders, compare their name; else if a is a folder, it's higher, else b is higher*…

Comment: What is the `sort_reverse` property? Should that be considered during sorting? Can you have items with *different* `sort_reverse` properties? What happens in that case? Also, same questions for the `sort` property.

Comment: why can you use for forloop in separately?

Comment: @VLAZ I was potentially going to use it with the sorting

Comment: @J.Do do you have to, or do you just use `name` and `is_folder`?

Comment: @VLAZ I don't have to. I can use any of the properties just so long as the result of the sorting is the one shown above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

- If the `is_folder` property is equal, then they are both files or both are folders. Compare their names
- Otherwise sort `is_folder === "Y"` higher

Ascending:

```js
const arr = [
  { "name": "Folder 3",  "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "2.jpg",     "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "Folder 2",  "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "Folder 10", "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "Folder 1",  "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "15.jpg",    "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "3.jpg",     "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "abc.txt",   "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "1.jpg",     "is_folder": "N" },
];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.is_folder === b.is_folder)
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, {numeric: true});
    
  if (a.is_folder === "Y")
    return -1;
    
  if (b.is_folder === "Y")
    return 1;
    
  return 0;
});

console.log(arr)
```

Descending:

```js
const arr = [
  { "name": "Folder 3",  "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "2.jpg",     "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "Folder 2",  "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "Folder 10", "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "Folder 1",  "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "15.jpg",    "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "3.jpg",     "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "abc.txt",   "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "1.jpg",     "is_folder": "N" },
];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.is_folder === b.is_folder)
    return b.name.localeCompare(a.name, undefined, {numeric: true}); //<-- flip `a` and `b`
    
  if (a.is_folder === "Y")
    return -1;
    
  if (b.is_folder === "Y")
    return 1;
    
  return 0;
});

console.log(arr)
```

[See on TypeScript Playground (including types)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLADYQMoE8DOkAtgJLHIDeAUMrciHERAFzKFSgDmA3DXcPgD6MAPYYAJtFYAiAJrTkAH2TSActN4BfKlQQiQhZHChRW6LHkIRSxANoBdZAF5ktvhRUMm0majGSoZABmaQAaWmkBYX9oHxV5ZE1Q909GCDjpACYAOgArAAdOMLoIqNEJWJl1ROTaD2kvdN8YwMzilTKWjISklIa0jL8KwIBGAAZiyKFygO6FXrrU72bh5BH2qejhuZq+xoyRgFY8wvbS6a6q+drKJaaVIJOi8JLNmcqVaoXb-uWVOAARghsmAAB5gM5vS6fa57AYyEZPM7nLazK67ey8KjGKDZfAiKBgAAURLg4QBAEpnAA+Sh8YAwZCk7KdVZOdnIAEsi7DCl8WhQCBgACuUBARmyjWyGBECDgWAAwiIiPljBAiVzGuFhSBJDBQBBxOEKCBhUwOAhWGAoMKIJoKbwSvTGczWQFnBy5NI+SVBSKxcgALQjR10Z1Mrlu6Aelxen10P2i8Uh-nIPiJgNjLQOnR6AxiCDSkScUkmHNAA)

Using [`localeCompare` with the numeric collation option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Numeric_sorting) ensures that numbers will be correctly sorted where `10` is *after* `2`, for example. Here is what happens if you don't use that:

```js
const arr = [
  { "name": "Folder 3",  "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "2.jpg",     "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "Folder 2",  "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "Folder 10", "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "Folder 1",  "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "15.jpg",    "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "3.jpg",     "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "abc.txt",   "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "1.jpg",     "is_folder": "N" },
];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.is_folder === b.is_folder)
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name); //<-- no numeric collation
    
  if (a.is_folder === "Y")
    return -1;
    
  if (b.is_folder === "Y")
    return 1;
});

console.log(arr)
```

As you can see, we basically repeat all the code to do the ascending/descending sort. This makes maintaining it harder, however we can improve it. We can extract each part into a separate function:

- sort names of similar items - ascending
- sort names of similar items - descending
- sort folders before files

Luckily, for ascending/descending flipping the order of `a` and `b` is the same as multiplying by `-1` since `localeCompare` returns a number - positive, negative, or zero. So, we can only have the logic once and not repeat it twice:

```
const compareFoldersFirst = (a, b) => {
  if (a.is_folder === "Y")
    return -1;

  if (b.is_folder === "Y")
    return 1;

  return 0;
}

const compareNameAsc = (a, b) => {
  if (a.is_folder === b.is_folder)
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, {numeric: true});

  return 0;
}

const compareNameDesc = (a, b) => compareNameAsc(a, b) * -1;
```

We can actually generalise the logic used in `compareNameDesc` - it just runs a function with two parameters and multiplies it by `-1`, so we can make a generic `reverse` function that can reverse any sorting order:

```js
const reverse = compareFn => (a, b) => compareFn(a, b) * -1;
const compareNameDesc = reverse(compareNameAsc);
```

In addition, we can slightly change the logic of each comparison to make it completely self sufficient, since right now the name sorting depends on whether something is a folder or not.

```
const compareFoldersFirst = (a, b) => {
  if (a.is_folder === b.is_folder)
    return 0;

  if (a.is_folder === "Y")
    return -1;

  if (b.is_folder === "Y")
    return 1;
};
```

This is even shorter to express with a slight..."creative usage" of the boolean and number conversion rules:

```js
const compareFoldersFirst = (a, b) => Number(b.is_folder === "Y") - Number(a.is_folder === "Y");
```

At any rate, this allows us to drop the `is_folder` check from the name comparison and we're left with simply the following comparers:

```
const compareFoldersFirst = (a, b) => Number(b.is_folder === "Y") - Number(a.is_folder === "Y");
const compareNameAsc = (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, {numeric: true});
const compareNameDesc = reverse(compareNameAsc);
```

We have *almost* all the tools we need to produce any sorting order we want by adding more logic *once* and then reverse it or not. We just need to be able to easily compose the different comparers. To do that, we can generalise the sorting as the following: We get *any number* of sorting functions. We produce a new function that will run them one by one until one returns a non-zero result at which point we return that. This can be done as

```
const comparer = (...comparers) => 
  (a, b) => {
    for(let compareFn of comparers){
       const result = compareFn(a, b);
       if (result !== 0) 
         return result;
    }
  }
```

But can be made more compact using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). In the end the code is easier to maintain and composable, using the helper `compare` function:

```js
const arr = [
  { "name": "Folder 3",  "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "2.jpg",     "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "Folder 2",  "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "Folder 10", "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "Folder 1",  "is_folder": "Y" },
  { "name": "15.jpg",    "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "3.jpg",     "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "abc.txt",   "is_folder": "N" },
  { "name": "1.jpg",     "is_folder": "N" },
];

//helper function that takes any amount of compare functions 
//produces a function that runs each until a non-zero result 
const compare = (...comparers) => 
  (a, b) => comparers.reduce(
    (result, compareFn) => result || compareFn(a, b),
    0
  );

//reverse the result of any compare function after it runs:
const reverse = compareFn  => (a, b) => compareFn (a, b) * -1;

//the basic comparer functions:
const compareFoldersFirst = (a, b) => Number(b.is_folder === "Y") - Number(a.is_folder === "Y");
const compareNameAsc = (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, {numeric: true});
const compareNameDesc = reverse(compareNameAsc);

//final comparison function derived form the basic ones
const asc = compare(
  compareFoldersFirst,
  compareNameAsc
);

const desc = compare(
  compareFoldersFirst,
  compareNameDesc
);

console.log("--- Ascending sort ---\n",  arr.sort(asc));
console.log("--- Descending sort ---\n", arr.sort(desc));
```

[See on TypeScript Playground (including types)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLADYQMoE8DOkAtgJLHIDeAUMrciHERAFzKFSgDmA3DXcPgD6MAPYYAJtFYAiAJrTkAH2TSActN4BfKlVCRYiFAGERRAA5woEVAFcQCMMBEgAPABUAfJT4AKOKzcAGmQAIwCASmRWEBsiEOgtHQRnQmRLKFZ0LDxCCFJiAG0AXWQAXmQCvgoVBiZpGVQxSShkAGZpYJUBYSboepV5ZE1AqprGCH7pACYAOgArM04OulppbtEJPpl1IZHaaulaiYbelqnlrqEN5snB4dHD8cnGzZaARgAGZbWr09uFe77MZ1E6vZBvC4-Hqvf67B5HSZvACs80WF1W6z+2wBe0owOOKlaqKWnToUOuWxUO0BeMeIJUcBCCBmYAAHmB0eSsVScfCnjI3sT0RjfjDsXCirwqAB6aUACwgGDM0GQMDsDicIGQYDlcDA2rgAGsIPg0iBcGkiCI7PqRDBkMlzJYUGr7I4UsgZdKzFAROIbEhTXBVer3VqdXrkFA7KaIIg5cgbZg0vRnABaABe0BEUZNNgw+qoyRAqUdFisZWQ7g8PhmdbLzqg+FYJidVlsbs11eK4RbpnL1lDXc8ZS8vn8QVCzDcvfosXiLVKXgbVibMys-qQPj4tB8Vnw+bAwRX1hAkSXuYPBaUyhPqBAfmCIXCuNoHz44SlsqsADdoPgUB1FB90PZA7TNC0TxDTtnDSGB9GQYB9WjEtmCLFJkIgP8mxQcpqx8O8QD7NtBxg1xPFnVsBw7DVnGrUcd2QPwAifCJRwdftnXvR9QkiAAqZA0zeL9pSA0I4HwYAEA4kiWldWjUPQkt9TvU58HQJswGI6ihzorIcAIYgyDyLxyh458GJWVR52gHwQhmTEwVKZyBmkSI02Qay4lsuAHNFZoyhcuQ3N4YtS04qxVHGABBfAEG0rjdNcfSciM4hTKYuAn3PDxGN8o4ZgwEQEDgLAqOdOyZiOYI7EkGBQAgcRgmqGImA4eLtWjFBNE-JTwpIqKmAAERNaTyl-f8IAIiKIEGiBYoQXqvXqhgMBk8sBFg+Sw2QZpgD-cRVREKAiG1BVxMk6TnBNPr9Qksb1oqvhVNedTgE03ETzmhaqCWsL9UkOLKxPbdaBe5o3o+56Zrmka4t+qUwrECBCpETgfGkNMseQBaIBAcQuDYY79SxtMAB0QAudIZnwYm-Di8JeqRrBUfRzHsbhpB8cJ2moBJrGKeWanebAHxAcW3qgA)

Comment: I've applied your original answer (please see updated question) but this does not seem to sort the files. It only sorts the folder

Comment: @J.Do you have a typo `a.is_foler` -> `a.is_folder`

Comment: It was indeed a typo. My bad. *facepalm*

Comment: @J.Do I've added links to the TS playground which uses types for the comparisons. This helps a lot, because `(a: any, b: any)` allows minor typos like what you had to slip through, if you restrict the types, you'd have seen an error because that property doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a sorty by folder in advance and then sort by name in wanted order.

```js
var data = [{ name: "test", is_folder: "Y", is_file: "N" }, { name: "1.jpg", is_folder: "N", is_file: "Y" }, { name: "abc", is_folder: "Y", is_file: "N" }, { name: "2.jpg", is_folder: "N", is_file: "Y" }];

// asc
data.sort((a, b) =>
    (b.is_folder === 'Y') - (a.is_folder === 'Y') || // static
    a.name.localeCompare(b.name)                     // dynamic
);
console.log(data);

// desc
data.sort((a, b) =>
    (b.is_folder === 'Y') - (a.is_folder === 'Y') ||
    b.name.localeCompare(a.name)
);
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```